# Dynamic filename in mysqldump - date

Tags: cron, mysql

So far I've tried:

```
'date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M"'_PostsOnly.sql
```

With output:

```
date\ +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M"_PostsOnly.sql
```

2)

```
'date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H\%M"_PostsOnly'.sql
```

With output:

```
date\ +"\\%Y-\\%m-\\%d_\\%H\\%M"_PostsOnly.sql
```

Anyone care to correct me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
localhost ~]$ echo $(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")_PostsOnly.sql
2012-03-23_1507_PostsOnly.sql
```

Comment: assuming it is bash or some other shell that is compatible.

Comment: echo is unnecessary for the mysqldump: mysqldump -u username -p my_db wp_posts wp_postmeta > /home/backups/mysql/$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")_PostsOnly.sql